# Call to a member function batchGet() on a non-object

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm working on getting some google analytics api stats and am able to get metrics just fine using this...

```
$results = getResults($analytics, $profile->getId(), $value);
$rows = $results->getRows();
$myvalue = $rows[0][0];
echo "<b>$value:</b> ". round($myvalue, 0) ."</br>";
```

but the below code throws an error (see post title) when I call batchGet using same analytics object that works in above code. Unsure why or if there is an alternative way to get the dimension data I'm after.

```
$device = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$device->setName("ga:deviceCategory");
// Create the ReportRequest object.
$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setDimensions(array($device));
$body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
$body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
```

Here is how I instantiate the $analytics object

```
function getService()
{
// service account email, and relative location of your key file.
$service_account_email = 'email@gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = 'pathto/file.p12';

// Create and configure a new client object.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Analytics");
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_email,
    array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY),
    $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}

return $analytics;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are instantiating the `$analytics` object?

Answer (score 1):

Still don't know why batchGet throws an error, but the code below works and will return the deviceCategories.

```
  $optParams = array(
  'dimensions' => 'ga:deviceCategory',
  'filters' => 'ga:medium==organic');

$devices = $analytics->data_ga->get(
  'ga:'.$profile->getId(),
  '2015-05-01',
  '2015-05-15',
  'ga:sessions',
  $optParams);

print_r($devices);
```